Copying a sent email to another folder after being sent MS Graph API
I am trying to copy a sent email to a specific folder once sent. The issue I am having is sometimes the email that is sent the draft is actually copied rather than the sent email. I am using immutable id's but its unclear why sometimes the draft would be sent.
My service layer does the following:
           if(emailDetails.ReplyToEmailId != null) {
                email = await _emailServices.SendReplyToEmailAsync("mmcratesetting@cms.hhs.gov", emailDetails.ReplyToEmailId!, emailDetails.Email);
            } else {
                email = await _emailServices.SendEmailAsync("mmcratesetting@cms.hhs.gov", emailDetails.Email);
            }

            //copy new email to folder
            if(email != null)
            {
                await _emailServices.CopyEmailByFolderIdAsync("mmcratesetting@cms.hhs.gov",email.Id, archiveFolder.Id);
            }

Then my actual code for creating draft and sending is as follows:
    public async Task<Models.Email?> SendReplyToEmailAsync(string mailBox, string messageId, AddEmailDTO email)
    {
        var requestBody = new CreateReplyPostRequestBody
        {
            Message = new Message
            {
                ToRecipients = email.To?.Select(contact => new Recipient
                {
                    EmailAddress = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.EmailAddress
                    {
                        Address = contact.EmailAddress,
                        Name = contact.Name
                    }
                }).ToList(),
                CcRecipients = email.Cc?.Select(contact => new Recipient
                {
                    EmailAddress = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.EmailAddress
                    {
                        Address = contact.EmailAddress,
                        Name = contact.Name
                    }
                }).ToList(),
                BccRecipients = email.Cc?.Select(contact => new Recipient
                {
                    EmailAddress = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.EmailAddress
                    {
                        Address = contact.EmailAddress,
                        Name = contact.Name
                    }
                }).ToList(),
                Subject = email.Subject,
                Body = new ItemBody
                {
                    ContentType = BodyType.Html,
                    Content = email.Body,
                },
                
            },
        };

        var result = await _graphServiceClient.Users[mailBox].Messages[messageId].CreateReply.PostAsync(requestBody, rc =>
        {
            rc.Headers.Add("Prefer", "IdType=\"ImmutableId\"");
        });
        
        if(result != null) 
        {
            await _graphServiceClient.Users[mailBox].Messages[result.Id].Send.PostAsync( rc =>
            {
                rc.Headers.Add("Prefer", "IdType=\"ImmutableId\"");
            });
            return await GetEmailAsync(mailBox, result.Id!); 
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public async Task CopyEmailByFolderIdAsync(string mailBox, string messageId, string folderId)
    {
        var requestBody = new CopyPostRequestBody
        {
            DestinationId = folderId,
            
        };

        var result = await _graphServiceClient.Users[mailBox].Messages[messageId].Copy.PostAsync(requestBody, rc =>
        {
            rc.Headers.Add("Prefer", "IdType=\"ImmutableId\"");
        });
    }

I am unsure what exactly I am doing wrong. I am using ImmutableId on each request as shown. If I walk through my code step by step it seems to work but if I let it run freely then this sometimes happens. Is it a issue on my end or how outlooks and MS Graph API work with Ids?

After PostASync, try to make delay like 2 secs for  GetEmailAsync and add check to mail object is in draft or not, by using IsDraft boolean

EmailObj = await GetEmailAsync(mailBox, result.Id!);
if(EmailObj.IsDraft == false)


Yea that might be a good idea. Could you write up a possible solution and I will give it a try? Any reason it would not work as is? Its unclear why their api would work in this manner.
